# I have been stuck on this code for awhile

Tags: java, class, text-files

My first code derives on what should be printed. I made a constructor and I used setters and getters to make this. Then ended it with a toString() method.

Book class:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.lang.*;
public class Book {
   
   // Initiate variables
   // Note: I used the DecimalFormat so every price is always going to have 2 decimal spaces
   private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
   private String ISBN;
   private String author;
   private String title;
   private int edition;
   private String pubCode;
   private int quantity;
   private double price;
   
   //constructor
   public Book(String isbn, String auth, String ti, int ed, String pc, int qty, double pr)
   {
      ISBN = isbn;
      author = auth;
      title = ti;
      edition = ed;
      pubCode = pc;
      quantity = qty;
      price = pr;
   }
   
   //getters
   public String getTitle(){return title;}
   public String getAuthor(){return author;}
   public double getPrice(){return price;}
   public int getEdition(){return edition;}
   public String getISBN(){return ISBN;}
   public String getpubCode(){return pubCode;}
   public int getQuantity(){return quantity;}
   
   //setters
   public void changePrice(double newPrice){price = newPrice;}
   public boolean changeQuantity(int changeAmt){
   changeAmt = quantity + changeAmt;
   if (changeAmt < 0) {
   return false;
   } 
   else {
   return true;
   }
   }

   //This prints out all of the information once the object 'Book' is used
   public String toString() 
   {
      String subAuthor = "";
      String subTitle = "";
      subAuthor = author.substring(0,16);
      subTitle = title.substring(0,32);
      return "ISBN: " +ISBN + "\nAuthor: " + subAuthor + "\nTitle: " + subTitle + "\nEdition: " + edition + "\nPublisher Code: " + pubCode + "\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\nPrice: $ " +df2.format(price) + "\n\n";
   }
}
```

Then I made a class called Inventory to manage instances of the Book class. However, I'm still not sure if most of my code is correct since I compiled it without any errors. What I mean is the constructor itself, the addBook method and the changeQuantity method.

The constructor takes one argument, which is the size of the books array. It should create the empty array of the specified size, and initializes the nextEntry field to be 0.

The addBook is made to add a Book object to the books array at the position specified by the nextEntry field, the nextEntry field is incremented by 1, and the method should returns true as an indication of success.  If the array is already full there is no space to add the new book, so the method returns false as an indication of failure.

The changeQuantity method should update the quantity of the specified book by adding the changeAmt(which may be positive or negative), unless the change will cause the final quantity to be negative.  The method will return true if successful, and false if the change would have resulted in a negative quantity.

The thing that also gets me is that I need to identify the proper Book object by iterating through the inventory to find the matching ISBN String. I'm assuming I need to use the .equals() method, but I have been trying to see if I can print everything first, so I haven't coded it yet.

Then I use the printInventory method. This method should print the entire inventory, using the toString()method on each book.

Inventory class:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Inventory {

   private Book[] books;
   private int nextEntry;
   int questionAmt;
   
   public Inventory(int size){
      size = 7; 
      books = new Book[size];
      nextEntry = 0; 
   }
   
   public boolean addBook(Book theBook) {
   if (nextEntry > 27)
   { return false;}
   else{
   nextEntry++;
   books[nextEntry] = theBook;
   return true;
   }
  }
   
   public boolean changeQuantity(String isbn, int changeAmt) {
      if (changeAmt < 0) {
         return false;
      } 
      else {
         return true;
      }
      }
   public void printInventory()
   {
   for  (int i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(books[i].toString()); 
   
   return;
   }
   }
```

Then I added the text file, which is called inventory. This is what should be shown in the code and I should be able to edit the quantity it inside the console. I also added a 28 because it needs 28 Books.

inventory.txt:

```
28
013478796X_Tony Gaddis_Starting Out with Java: From Control Structures through Data Structures_4_PE_10_121.75
0321409493_John Lewis_Java Software Solutions: Foundations of Program Design_5_AW_12_94.05
0023606924_Richard Johnsonbaugh_Algorithms_1_PH_1_109.00
0134743350_Harvey Dietel_Java: How to Program, Early Objects_12_PE_12_134.84
0131474340_Ralph Morelli_Java, Java, Java, Object-Oriented Problem Solving_3_PH_4_95.25
0596100469_Alex Martelli_Python in a Nutshell_2_OR_6_39.99
0134802217_Tony Gaddis_Starting Out with Java: From Control Structures through Objects_7_PE_8_118.67
1403946876_Sally Fincher_Studying Programming_1_PM_3_26.59
0596510047_Andy Oram_Beautiful Code: Leading Programmers Explain How They Think_1_OR_5_44.99
0143037889_Ray Kurzweil_The Singularity is Near: When Humans Transcend Biology_1_PG_20_17.70
0135205972_John Lewis_Java Foundations: Introduction to Program Design and Data Structures_5_PE_5_129.99
0131872893_Wanda Dann_Learning to Program with Alice_1_PH_12_47.50
159413962X_Dave Eggers_The Circle_1_AW_4_3.99
1887902996_John Zelle_Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science_1_FB_2_26.40
0133356728_Rafael Gonzales_Digital Image Processing_4_PE_3_248.17
1592400876_Lynne Truss_Eats, Shoots & Leaves_1_PG_5_17.70
0072823798_William Collins_Data Structures and the Java Collections Framework_2_MH_6_105.57
0072866098_Allen Tucker_Programming Languages: Principles and Paradigms_2_MH_1_127.50
0534950973_Michael Sipser_Introduction to the Theory of Computation_2_CT_3_98.90
0131496710_Francis Hill_Computer Graphics Using OpenGL 3rd Edition_3_PH_4_112.00
0321173486_Dave Shreiner_OpenGL Programming Guide_5_AW_1_24.00
0072865512_Steven Schach_Object Oriented and Classical Software Engineering_6_MH_9_123.44
0321228383_Michael Kifer_Database Systems: An Application-Oriented Approach_2_AW_3_112.86
1416587787_Cliff Stoll_The Cuckoo's Egg_1_PG_3_13.32
1400032717_Mark Haddon_The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time_1_VI_10_13.95
006025492X_Maurice Sendak_Where the Wild Things Are_1_HC_6_17.95
0694003611_Margaret Brown_Goodnight Moon_1_HC_138_8.99
069401298X_Arnold Lobel_Frog and Toad Together_1_HC_27_11.55
```

Last, but not least, I made an InventoryTester file to read the text file and print it using the code from  both classes.

InventoryTester:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class InventoryTester {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner inFile= new Scanner(new File("inventory.txt"));
      Book books;
      String inLine= inFile.nextLine();
      int size= Integer.parseInt(inLine);
      Inventory myInventory= new Inventory(size);
      
      while (inFile.hasNext()) {
      inLine= inFile.nextLine();
      String ISBN = inFile.next();       
      String author = inFile.next(); 
      String title = inFile.next();
      int edition = inFile.nextInt();
      String pubCode = inFile.next();
      int quantity = inFile.nextInt();
      double price = inFile.nextDouble();
      myInventory.addBook(new Book(ISBN, author, title, edition, pubCode, quantity, price));
      String[] tokens  = inLine.split("_");
      myInventory.printInventory(); 
      }
      
      inFile.close();
      }
      }
```

My problem with this code is that I keep receiving a mismatch exception.

Edit: I completely forgot to add the error. Sorry about that!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at InventoryTester.main(InventoryTester.java:22)
```

I was trying to make Java understand that there are strings, ints, and doubles. It should print along with what I need to change for the quantity, but I can't seem to see if I have the right code to make this work with this error in my way.

If you can help me with this error and if you can let me know if I have the Inventory class done correctly or not, I would appreciate it.

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask to look at. You say there is a "mismatch" exception, but don't show the stack trace or what line of code is throwing the error. Please edit the question and add the details. thanks

Comment: You included quite a lot of information there... what you did not do, however, is include the exact text of the error message you received. Was it an InputMismatchException you got? Edit  your question to include the stack trace, including the exact error message. Then you can remove your code, with the exception of the section of code that throws the exception. The error message will include a line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to do in the test file is to read each line, split it with _ and then assign it to each value via the constructor.
But the code does not appear to be doing that.

```
inLine= inFile.nextLine();
```

This reads the entire line into inLine. You are then doing `infile.next` after that which will read the subsequent line not the same line. `nextline` method moves the pointer to the next line
Also you are splitting the line at the end, but not using it, so lets read a line, split it and then use each string one by one.

This should work better for your use case:

```
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
inLine= inFile.nextLine();
String[] tokens  = inLine.split("_");
String ISBN = tokens[0];       
String author = tokens[1]; 
String title = tokens[2];
int edition = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
String pubCode = tokens[4];
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
double price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[6]);
myInventory.addBook(new Book(ISBN, author, title, edition, pubCode, quantity, price));
      
myInventory.printInventory(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped with the mismatch!